# How to live with both enum and enum34?

Tags: python, enums

I noticed a different behaviour with enum on Python.

I was first surprised to notice the output for this was an `int`:

```
>>>import enum
>>>class Color(enum.Enum):
       red = 1

>>>Color.red
1
```

Then I realized I had `enum` installed instead of `enum34`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-enum34
```

And now, the result is different:

```
>>>Color.red
<Color.red: 1>
```

My current application is accepting `enum` types where I get the value of the enum with `value.value`. Of course this will raise an exception if the wrong enum is installed.

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Are you talking about some `enum` module other than the standard-library `enum`? The one in the standard library shouldn't have given you the result you saw.

Comment: I don't know. I just ran a fresh install of `ipython` and tried this example. I got the former output. Then I installed `enum34` and I got the latter result.

Comment: A fresh install should have given you either an ImportError or the result you wanted, depending on your Python version. Are you sure you remembered to inherit from `enum.Enum`? The code snippets you've shown clearly aren't copy-pasted from an actual interpreter session.

Comment: What was `enum.__file__`? Perhaps you have some other stray `enum` module on your system somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a guess, it looks like you had the `enum` package that existed before the 3.4 Enum came in to being. `enum34` is so named because that previous package already existed.

Both `enum` and `enum34` install to the same location, so making them co-exist is not easy -- plus it would make your code difficult to distribute as one of the enums would be in a non-standard location.

One possibility is to use [`virtual envs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) -- then you can install whichever enum is needed for the application in the `venv`.

Comment: This, venvs and you can limit packages and not worry about awkward collisions between projects.

Comment: Say more about "Both enum and enum34 install to the same location." A virtual env can have both pips installed. `pip list` lists both. In both cases one is supposed to do `from enum import Enum`. What determines which enum package gets loaded?

Comment: Oh! `import enum; print(enum.__file__)` leads me to `site-packages/` containing both `enum-0.4.6.dist-info` and `enum34-1.1.6.dist-info`, while the installed one in `.../site-packages/enum` has a README that's clear that this is enum34.

Comment: @Jerry101:  The one that gets loaded is the one that was installed last.

Comment: Thanks, @EthanFurman. With `pip install -r requirements.txt` pip decides what order to install packages. So if requirements.txt lists both, will everyone get the same result?

Comment: @Jerry101:  I do not know.  The correct answer, though, is don't do that; use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting @Jerry101's comment in another answer, here's what I landed on:

```
def is_using_enum34(self):
    try:
        import enum
        return enum.__file__.__str__().endswith("__init__.pyc")
    except:
        return False
    return False
```

I noticed that for:
enum34: `enum.__file__` == `__init__.pyc`
enum: `enum.__file__` == `enum.pyc`.

I've not heavily used this and it's probably non-ideal, but it suits what I'm looking at and may be helpful for others.